# Readline accept int from console in C

Tags: c, input, int, readline

I would like to have readline accept an int. What is the best way to accomplish this? I have no problem accepting string input like so:

```
 char *usrname; // define user input

 /* accept input */
 printf("Enter new name:");
 usrname = readline(NULL);
```

I do understand that having an int will require some error checking on the before accepting the input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Eduardo Costa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980699/readline-accept-int-from-console-in-c/4980727#4980727) works, but it leaks memory. It's better to define a function to take care of this for you:

```
int readint(char *p, char **e)
{
    char *c = readline(p);
    int i = strtol(c, e, 0);
    if(e)
      {
        size_t o = (size_t)(*e - c),
               l = strlen(*e) + 1;
        *e = malloc(l);
        // error checking omitted
        memcpy(*e, c + o, l);
      }
    free(c);
    return i;
}
```

This version will even preserve any extra stuff on the line so you can use it later if you need it. Of course, if you need to do a lot with the extra stuff you may be better off just reading the line and parsing it yourself rather than with functions like this.

Comment: Isn't it easier to either use `*e = strdup(*e);` in the `if`?  Or, if you decide that `strdup()` is too POSIX-ish, then use: `size_t len = strlen(*e) + 1; char *str = malloc(len); if (str) { memcpy(str, *e, len); *e = str; }`.  I'm also not completely convinced that `e` is being used as it should; there is a double usage going on - my second alternative revision shows that more clearly as it introduces `str` to avoid storing two values in `*e` at the same time.

Comment: @Jonathan - It could be clearer or easier, and actually reexamining it made me realize it had an error, but (now that it's fixed) it should work fine. Your version is cleaner though, and `strdup` does make this whole thing a lot easier.

Comment: I think you're copying the data in the wrong direction - it should be `memcpy(*e, c + o, l);`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Jonathan - Indeed. Writing code from my iPhone without checking it is a bad strategy.

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried something like this?

```
int i = atoi(readline(NULL));
```

Comment: -1 this makes it impossible to `free` the string returned by `readline`, which is a pretty serious problem.

Comment: Also `atoi` has undefined behavior if the value does not fit in an `int`. Using `strtol` would be much preferred.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I made it too naive, assuming a simple problem (like the ones I had to solve way back in my college) - since reading a int using C+readline does not looks like a complex problem.